# How do I force Pelican to suppress generation of category files?

Tags: pelican

I don't want Pelican 3.6 to generate:

```
/author/
/category/
/tag/
/archives.html
/authors.html
/categories.html
/tags.html
```

`DIRECT_TEMPLATES` can be set to suppress some of the index files:-

```
# DIRECT_TEMPLATES = ['index', 'categories', 'authors', 'archives']
DIRECT_TEMPLATES = ['index']
```

Omitting tag metadata in source content files will prevent generation of the tag folder and index; omitting author metadata and the `AUTHOR` setting will prevent generation of the author folder and index.

But it seems that suppressing category isn't so simple.  I've tried setting `DEFAULT_CATEGORY` to an empty string, but this results in errors and no output for sources with no category metadata:-

```
Skipping <some_file>: could not find information about 'NameError: category'
```

I've also tried removing the relevant template files from the theme being used, but this merely causes them to be replaced with the matching template in the built-in "simple" theme.

Am I missing an established method of suppressing category generation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [URL settings documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#url-settings) has a long list of settings, including several `[…]_SAVE_AS` settings. Directly below the URL settings table is a note that answers your question: for any page type that you do not want generated, set the corresponding `[…]_SAVE_AS` setting to `''`. For example, to suppress individual category page generation, add this setting:

```
CATEGORY_SAVE_AS = ''
```

and to suppress the `categories.html` page, add:

```
CATEGORIES_SAVE_AS = ''
```